# iOS UIWebView failed to find PDF header after converting PDF as String to NSData

Tags: ios, swift, encoding

I'm trying to download a PDF and display it in a UIWebView. The API is giving me the PDF as a String, looking like this:

[image]

I convert the string to NSData:

```
self.fileData = responseObject!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```

Then i load it into my WebView, however i am getting:

```
failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found.
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: PDF files are not guaranteed to not contain bytes that would be corrupted if interpreted in some string encoding rather than kept as binary data - they are best treated as binary. You say that "the API" gives it to you as a string. Which method is this? And how do you load it into your web view?

Answer (score 0):

You could save the string as a file, with String's `writetoFile` method for example, then grab this file directly from the webview with UIWebView's `loadRequest` method.

Note that usually a PDF encoded as a String should be encoded as Base64 String. If this is the case for your String, then you could use NSData's `base64EncodedString` initializer to read the string content as data.